# How to import file on Dynamic 365 using Azure Function

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, dynamic365

I have one CSV file that file I want to upload on Dynamic365 using Azure Function.

Comment: You can use `Dynamics 365 Web API` to upload csv file. For more details, [please check this post](https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/414053/upload-sharepoint-document-using-dynamics-365-web-api).

Comment: @Jason Pan Thanks for the response but can we make REST call from Azure function and send file on Dynamic365?

Comment: absolutely you can

Comment: Do you have any sample code ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

Comment: you can use httpclient to call restapi

Comment: Thank you Jason !! I will try from my end.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Jason Pan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7687666/jason-pan) and [DnyaneshSurya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15120444/dnyaneshsurya) for your valuable discussions. Posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Use Dynamics 365 Web API to upload the CSV files.
>
> 1. use the entity ["sharepointdocumentlocations"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/sharepointdocumentlocation?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)
> 2. Create an Azure function to generate an REST API Call.

Reference : https://community.dynamics.com/365/f/dynamics-365-general-forum/414053/upload-sharepoint-document-using-dynamics-365-web-api